# Creating Multiple portals from a site and serving the portals

Tags: php

I need to build a strategy or plan for implementation of a site

the situation is the following:

i have a site for people which belong to a community say xyz.
now i need to provide an account for the individuals of such communities on my site
when they logs into my site, there will be a feature to build a portal for themselves with some functionalities
like wise when n no of people logs in they might create n no of portal for themselves with some functionalities
the people will also create or use a n no of domain name respectively for the portal.

my problem or questions is:

1. How can i plan to create such a website?
2. Do i have to create separate code base files for each individual portal? or my current website portal code base can serve for each individual created portals?
3. How can i setup the site at domain automatically?

Update 1

I think the main website will already have a domain name for it
The other portals created through the main website will also have domain name for themselves as they are for some users

but the question is i have my main website domain name already using the code base which is serving the main website, now can i create domain names through my main website for the users and also ask the newly created domain names to use the same code base of my main website?

Actually i am planning to create domains through my application(please guide how can i create domain from my application) than after creating the domain can i ask the newly created domain to use the code base of my website which created the domain.
than there in the code base i do a domain name check as suggested in few other forums i guess, and load the content for the portal in the newly created domin

is this possible? if yes also can you guide me how can i:

1. create domains from my application? and than
2. during domain creation process through my application, how can i configure the new domain being created to my application code base?
3. is this the right way of implementing it?

Comment: This question may be te broad. In short a few hints: (a) if your code checks the Host header, you can have it all in 1 document root (b) If the IP stays the same, just have a wildcard vhost listening to _any_ host header & you'll only have to set up / store your 'domains' in some persistant layer (database et al.).

Comment: Wrikken,

Please check my answer and comment on it with you view,

thanks

Comment: If you need to clarify things, edit the question, don't add it as an answer. The answers are: yes it is possible, yes you can use the same codebase, yes examining the host & url is a fine way to work. However, I stand by the fact this is overly broad, if you run into trouble, try to carve it into smaller individual problems.

Comment: Hey Wrikken, sorry for that earlier thing,
have updated the question, can you review it and give your idea about it now??
thanks

Comment: You shouldn't write "thanks" every time you edit. Even if it's a common courtesy, it's regarded as an unwanted noise in this community.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How can i plan to create such a website?

Think about what exactly it is that the user requires. They have made an account, and want a portal to their own personal domain on the server. A domain on a server is just a file, so when they create that new portal, you might want to simply add a new HTML file under a logical directory, and populate it with some standard HTML.

> 2)Do I have to create separate code base files for each individual portal? or my current website portal code base can serve for each individual created portals?

I guess you can make the difference specified by a query string in the URL. For example, add database values for each user, and do something like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/portal.php?id=40395
```

Your page will then use that `id` value, and take values from the database to populate the page with. That way you only have one file, `portal.php`, but it serves for any number of people.

> 3)How can i setup the site at domain automatically?

Like I said, the domain is just a file on the server. For example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/files/directory/hello.php
```

is just referring to the structure of files on the server. Namely:

```
www.mywebsite.com
       files
            directory
                      hello.php
```

If you place a file, `goodbye.php` in the same place, you can access it in a similar way.

```
www.mywebsite.com/files/directory/goodbye.php
```

***PLEASE NOTE*** : You have provided no code, so I don't feel obliged to provide any in return. If you haven't took a swing at the problem of implementing the solution, then I guess I won't either.